# can any one tell me what is missing in my code please, i cant use the discord user name

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want the user to start with 40 points, but if he already started just send how many points he has.

The error that im currently geting is: message is a required argument that is missing.
But i dont know what is missing.

```
async def money(self, ctx, message):
    user = message.author
    read = open(user, 'a').close()

    if os.stat(user).st_size == 0:
        moneyfile=open(user, 'w')
        moneyfile.write('40')
        moneyfile.close()
    else:
        readfile = open(user, 'r').read()
        points=readfile
        int(points)
        await ctx.send(points)
```

Comment: read the error again and look to your first line. You are missing the last parameter in the call to money. I suggest doing some tutorials on calling functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error reads itself, you are doing the command but not entering a message param. To fix this, delete the message param and set user in the 2nd line to ctx.author.